# Assistance with ControlSend to loop a keystroke to a background program

Tags: autohotkey

Specifically I'm trying to have autohotkey send the F keyboard key every two minutes to a window called Dawn of Fantasy while the program is in the background so i can do other things without having to be AFK logged out.

Currently I've been trying

```
Loop {

SetTimer, PressTheKey, 240000 Return

PressTheKey: ControlSend,,f,Dawn of Fantasy Return } F12::Pause
```

But I'm not sure its doing its job or if i messed up the coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `Loop` or `{`braces`}` if you have `SetTimer`

```
SetTimer, PressTheKey, 120000
Return

PressTheKey:
    ControlSend,,f,Dawn of Fantasy
Return

F12::Pause
```

If it still doesn't work, make sure you have correct window title and supposedly sometimes this approach helps (`down>sleep>up`) when it comes to games (directX):

(`ahk_parent` as control is another tweak that might help)

```
PressTheKey:
    ControlSend,ahk_parent,{f down},Dawn of Fantasy
    Sleep 250
    ControlSend,ahk_parent,{f up},Dawn of Fantasy
Return
```

Comment: Thanks Bob. Ill try it out.

Comment: I copy/pasted the 1st answer but set at 1200 (1.2seconds) to see if it was working. It wasnt sending as active or background. 

I copy/pasted the 2nd answer and oddly it closes the program (closes AHK) without explanation including gone from task manager.


Also the Task manager name of the client is Dof (32 bit) but the drop down has Dawn of Fantasy which is the game window's name if it helps any.